# Two Type of Nodes in a Single Check Box Node Tree

Tags: java, swing, editor, jtree

1. I need to render Two type of nodes in a single tree.

   Parent nodes and Leaf nodes.
2. I also need to edit both of them .

The CheckBoxNodeRender is as follows :

```
public JCheckBox leafRenderer;
public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
    boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
    boolean hasFocus) {
Component returnValue;  

if (leaf) {
    String stringValue =
        tree.convertValueToText(value, selected, expanded, leaf,
            row, false);

    if (selected) {
    leafRenderer.setForeground(selectionForeground);
    leafRenderer.setBackground(selectionBackground);
    } else {
    leafRenderer.setForeground(textForeground);
    leafRenderer.setBackground(textBackground);
    }
    if ((value != null) && (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode)) {
    Object userObject =
        ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();
    if (userObject instanceof CheckBoxNode) {
        CheckBoxNode node = (CheckBoxNode) userObject;


        leafRenderer.setText(node.getText());

        System.err.println("Leaf Value = "+node.getText());
        leafRenderer.setSelected(node.isSelected());
    }

    }
    returnValue = leafRenderer;
}
else {

    // For the Parent Node

   leafRenderer.setText(value.toString());
   leafRenderer.setSelected(selected);
   returnValue = leafRenderer;
}
return returnValue;
}
```

And the Editor is as follows :

```
public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject event) {
    //All cells are editable
return true;
   }

 public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
    boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row) {
Component editor =
    renderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value,
        true, expanded, leaf, row, true);


ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent itemEvent) {
    if (stopCellEditing()) {
        fireEditingStopped();
    }
    }
};
if (editor instanceof JCheckBox) {
    ((JCheckBox) editor).addItemListener(itemListener);
}


return editor;
}
```

I have been facing a unique problem here . 
When i select the parent node and select some other node , the value of the other node gets set for the parent node.
Any leads ?
What mistake am i doing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have your customized TreeCellEditor reusing components returned from your customized TreeCellRenderer, is that correct? That seems like a bad practice to me. The default JLabel-based implementation of TreeCellRenderer uses a single JLabel for rendering a large tree - so even if the tree has 1,000 nodes, only one JLabel instance is needed. If you're reusing this component when displaying your editor, this will result in graphical anomalies.

My recommendation would be to change your TreeCellEditor implementation to return a different component than the one being used for your TreeCellRenderer.

Comment: Can you give a snippet of how i can do it ?